# Android: Unable to set/retrieve data from intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to schedule local notifications in my app. Here is my `RootReceiver` class.

```
public class RebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String EVENT_CATEGORY = "notification_event";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Debug.waitForDebugger();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmScheduler.class);
    PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (!GeneralMethods.getBooleanPreference(context, ProperatiPreferences.APP_FIRST_LAUNCH)) {
        intent1.putExtra(EVENT_CATEGORY, "");
        now.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(), intentExecuted);
    } else if (!GeneralMethods.getBooleanPreference(context, ProperatiPreferences.SEARCH_AFTER_THREE_DAYS)) {
        intent1.putExtra(EVENT_CATEGORY, "");
        now.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(), intentExecuted);
    }
}
}
```

In here as you can see, I want to create an intent in which I want to put some data (`intent1`). However the intent is always empty without any extras inside of it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I try to retrieve extras from the intent.

```
public class AlarmScheduler extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String EVENT_CATEGORY = "notification_event";

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.d("com.properati.user", "AlarmScheduler.onReceive() called");

    Intent eventService = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    context.startService(eventService);
}
```

and finally my `AlarmService` class:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

private String EVENT_CATEGORY = "notification_event";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
    Log.d("com.properati.user", "event received in service: " + new Date().toString());

    if(intent.getStringExtra(EVENT_CATEGORY).equals(ProperatiPreferences.APP_FIRST_LAUNCH)){
        new PushNotification(getApplicationContext()).scheduleNonOpenedNotification(getApplicationContext());
    }else if(intent.getStringExtra(EVENT_CATEGORY).equals(ProperatiPreferences.SEARCH_AFTER_THREE_DAYS)){
        new PushNotification(getApplicationContext()).scheduleNoSearchAfterThreeDays(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in AlarmScheduler class

```
public class AlarmScheduler extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String EVENT_CATEGORY = "notification_event";
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.d("com.properati.user", "AlarmScheduler.onReceive() called");
    Intent eventService = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    eventService.putExtra(intent.getStringExtra(EVENT_CATEGORY, ""));
    context.startService(eventService);
}
```

Comment: Yes my friend this was the correct answer. I was missing that the extras are not send to the third activity! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

after I checked the PendingIntent source in Android framework, the intent argument will be cloned by `new Intent(intent)`. so you need set all data to intent1 before passing it to PendingIntent constructor.

```
@Override
public IIntentSender getIntentSender(int type,
        String packageName, IBinder token, String resultWho,
        int requestCode, Intent[] intents, String[] resolvedTypes,
        int flags, Bundle options, int userId) {
    enforceNotIsolatedCaller("getIntentSender");
    // Refuse possible leaked file descriptors                                                                                                                                                                  
    if (intents != null) {
        if (intents.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Intents array length must be >= 1");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<intents.length; i++) {
            Intent intent = intents[i];
            if (intent != null) {
                if (intent.hasFileDescriptors()) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File descriptors passed in Intent");
                }
                if (type == ActivityManager.INTENT_SENDER_BROADCAST &&
                        (intent.getFlags()&Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE) != 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "Can't use FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE here");
                }
                intents[i] = new Intent(intent);
            }
        }
        if (resolvedTypes != null && resolvedTypes.length != intents.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Intent array length does not match resolvedTypes length");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even so no success the intent received in Alarm service is still null